# to give space between two continuous uppercase letter

Tags: regex

I need to know how to give space between two uppercase letter continuously.

Ihave large list of customer. with first name middle name and last name. GaryACloud should be split as Gary A Cloud. I used `(.)([A-Z])` And replaced with `\1 \2.` I have no clue what it means.
 So if anyone can explain i will be really grateful. the above gave me a partial 
output only. i got Gary ACloud but how to provide space before every upper case
 letter? and also if you can expalin the solution, it will be very helpful

Comment: What's the full regex you were using?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Does your code work with "GaryTheCloud"?

Comment: I am using this in notepad ++.
The string will be in the following format
GaryMWilliams and i need to change it as Gary M Williams any suggestion please? because the above regex makes it as Gary MWilliams.i want to add space between M and W

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can match:

```
"([A-Z])(?=[A-Z])"
```

And replace with:

```
"\1 "
```

Comment: @Jongware: Fair point though question has has been edited multiple times in last hour. OP please tell me in which language you are writing this code so that I can provide you full code. e.g. PHP doesn't need any `/g` option but Javascript does.

Comment: i am using it for notepad++

Comment: It works , but it seperates the upper case when two upper case are there. with two search i was able to get it done good. first replace (.)([A-Z]) with \1 \2 and second search using yours. but is there a way to club both together? it will be better help. anyway my question was answered, and I'm marking it as answer. Thank you very much mr.anubhava. As your name suggests, i guess you have good experience in this field. Double like! thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome. If you understood meaning of my name that means you must be very good in Hindi :)

Comment: I know sanskrit. i studied it when i studied vedas. I am from tamilnadu. I do know hindi to some extend.

Comment: Ah that's true of course Sanskrit is mother of most of Indian languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "CategoryName";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z])([A-Z])", @"$1 $2"); //Category Name
```

UPDATE (this will treat sequence of capital letters as one word)

```
var input = "SimpleHTTPRequest";
var result = Regex.Replace(input, "([a-z]|[A-Z]{2,})([A-Z])", @"$1 $2");
```

//Simple HTTP Request